# Importing Python functions using pythontex

Tags: pythontex

I have a lengthy Python script (for a ML project), and I want to use some results in a LaTeX report. Using `pythontex`, I import my project, and it properly displays anything printed in `project.py` (e.g. `print("Hello World")` prints properly in the LaTeX pdf). However, it does not preserve variables or function definitions - so I can not use a variable defined in my `project.py` within a `\pycode{}` in my .tex file.

Any suggestions for why this is occurring, or how to get around it?

Edit - added example:

**code.py**

```py
print(3)
i = 4
```

**draft.tex**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\begin{document}
   Some text
   \begin{pycode}
      import code
      print(1)
      #print(i)
   \end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

When run as above, `draft.pdf` has `Some text 3 1`. If I uncomment `print(i)`, I get an error when running `pythontex`.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?  That would give us something to start from.

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured out a solution - 
using

```
from code import *
```

works (executes my code, and preserved variable and function definitions).

Comment: You should also be able to access variables and functions with `code.i`, etc. if you just used `import code` instead of importing `*`.